# Problem with primefaces dataTable when I use List<String>

Tags: primefaces

Anyone have any idea why the following,

```
<p:dataTable id="tblFileList" value="#{bean.fileNames}" var="f" rowIndexVar="row" style="width:700px;">
   <p:column headerText="#" style="width:100px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{row+1}" styleClass="en" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:100px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{f}" styleClass="en" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

give me following nonsense,

[image]

Comment: With 95% certainty, the css **_you_** apply messes things up creating this 'nonsense'. Or are you actually saying that when using a `List<MyObject>` it all works. And please learn how and why to create an [mcve] before posting and when debugging.

Comment: Maybe make that 100%... 100 pixels plus 100 pixels is not 700 pixels